# Trying to get my tweepy listener to work at intervals

Tags: python, time, tweepy

This is a modified version of a code I have to stream tweets. Now I am trying to add some lines to make it comply with the rate limits of twitter, but I can't make it work. My goal is to let it run for a while avoiding all the errors.

```
start_time = time.time() #grabs the system time

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit):
        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.tweet_data = []

    def on_data(self, data):
        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:
            try:
                with open('unlimited.json', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(data)
                    return True
            except BaseException as e:
                print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
            return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        time.sleep(5)
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(start_time, time_limit=20))
```

Comment: I think it is different. My error comes from python. Aparently some identation is wrong. Or maybe some part of the code related to time

Comment: what parameters are you using to get the rate limit? [`print(sapi.filter(track=['python']))`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html)

Comment: Im also not exactly sure of that but I believe that setting the time_limit to 15 minutes, can work?

Comment: sure, sounds good, try that and if you get rate limit message or any errors post them for further feedback.

Comment: the parameters are the following: sapi.filter(locations=[-73.79,-11.12,-34.41,-4.29,-70.23,-4.29,-34.41,2.67,-52.37,2.67,-50.61,5.41,-65.03,2.67,-59.33,5.41,-65.31,-14.2,-36.76,-11.11,-60.6,-16.43,-38.45,-14.2,-58.49,-22.4,-38.73,-16.43,-55.96,-24.27,-41.83,-22.4,-55.96,-28.37,-46.61,-24.27,-57.65,-31.65,-48.43,-28.37,-54.27,-33.96,-51.6,-31.65])

Comment: And the errors is: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: that error is from using tab and 4 spaces, replace every indent with 4 spaces, not tab, and try run script again. if you get error, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53909540/edit) question and include text of full Traceback. thanks,